# Basic Python dictionary question

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with one key and two values and I want to set each value to a separate variable.

d= {'key' : ('value1, value2'),
       'key2' : ('value3, value4'),
       'key3' : ('value5, value6')}

I tried d[key][0] in the hope it would return "value1" but instead it return "v"

Any suggestions?

Comment: that's not "two values", it's one value: a string.

Comment: Your editing of the question has caused answers to no longer make any sense...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A better solution is to store your value as a two-tuple:

```
d = {'key' : ('value1', 'value2')}
```

That way you don't have to split every time you want to access the values.

Comment: Ok I agree I think this is a better idea also, but I am still in the dark as to the syntax required to extract the values separately?

Comment: @Joe:  `d['key'][0]` and `d['key'][1]`

Comment: @Adam Bernier: I tried that but it gives me the first letter of each string...? help!

Comment: A better way would be to use tuple decomposition: `v1, v2 = d['key']`

Comment: @Joe: please update the question with the code you are trying.  My guess is that you have a minor syntax error, but we cannot help if we do not see what you are doing.

Comment: @Joe: based on your edit, your problem is that you are still using one string. Pay careful attention to the quotes: `d= {'key' : ('value1', 'value2'), 'key2' : ('value3', 'value4'), 'key3' : ('value5', 'value6')}`

Comment: @Adam Bernier: Haha many thanks, thats what happens when you have been working over 12 hours. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @Joe:  no worries; happens to us all.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
d = {'key' : 'value1, value2'}

list = d['key'].split(', ')
```

`list[0]` will be "value1" and `list[1]` will be "value2".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest storing lists in your dictionary. It'd make it much easier to reference. For instance,

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
my_dict["key"].append("value 1")
my_dict["key"].append("value 2")

print my_dict["key"][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the two values and assign them to value1 and value2:

```
for v in d.itervalues():
    value1, value2 = v.split(', ')
```

As said by zenazn, I wouldn't consider this to be a sensible data structure, using a tuple or a class to store the multiple values would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're storing your values, you'll need something like:

```
value1, value2 = d['key'].split(', ')
print value1, value2
```

or to iterate over all values:

```
for key in d:
    v1, v2 = d[k].split(', ')
    print v1, v2
```

But, if you can, you should probably follow zenazn's suggestion of storing your values as tuples, and avoid the need to split every time.